# Why are Bose-Einstein Condensates (BECs) named after Bose and Einstein?

Tags: history, specific-reference, bose-einstein-condensate

1. Why are [Bose-Einstein Condensates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bose%E2%80%93Einstein_condensate) (BECs) named after Bose and Einstein?
2. What did Einstein contribute to BECs?
3. What were the relevant papers by Bose and Einstein?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, Einstein was the first to consider a system of massive Bose particles and describe their condensation. I remember reading the relevant paper, but it will take me some time to find the reference.

EDIT (6/22/2016): I guess the paper is Sitzungsberichte der Preussischen Akademie der Wissenschaften (1924), 261